Duplicating entries in textfile for empty entries until a non-empty entry is found, then continue with the new entry
I have a very large textfile in which some entries are missing. The logic is persistent, as the first line of each "section" has the correct entries, every line after this initial line is missing these entries. I'm trying to update every line which misses these entries with the information from the initial line until a new "inital information line" is found. After that I'm continuing with this new found data.
I have build a solution in bash with the help of sed, but the process is very, very slow and takes hours to complete. I guess the reason for the delay is the fact that I'm reading line by line, process these in bash and write them to a new file. My guess is that a sed script with variables and on the file itself (-f) could speed up the process dramatically. I'm not an expert in these advanced usages of sed. I am open to other suggestions or tools, too - as long as they can be called from a bash script, as this is part of an automation.
The example inputfile:
{"Initial line with more information like headers, unimportant, really only one line"
"Alpha","OldTheme","Some more text"]
"","","Another rest text"]
"","","Yet another text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","Crazy Text"]
"","","More crazy text"]

The expected result:
"Alpha","OldTheme","Some more text"]
"Alpha","OldTheme","Another rest text"]
"Alpha","OldTheme","Yet another text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","Crazy Text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","More crazy text"]

And here's my working (but very slow) bash script:
#!/bin/bash
first=0
cat inputfile | \
while read line; do
        if [ ${first} -eq 0 ]; then
                first=1; continue
        fi
        partline=$(echo "${line}" | grep -o '","\(.*\)')
        newinitial=$(echo "${line}" | sed 's/",".*//; s/^"//')
        if [ ! -z "${newinitial}" ]; then
                initial=${newinitial}
        fi
        newtheme=$(echo "${partline}" | sed 's/^","//; s/",".*//')
        if [ ! -z "${newtheme}" ]; then
                theme=${newtheme}
        fi
        restline=$(echo ${partline} | sed 's/^","//' | grep -o '","\(.*\)')
        echo "\"${initial}\",\"${theme}${restline}"
done >outputfile

Clarification: The input is NOT a well-formed CSV, the first line starts indeed with a { and every line ends with a ], therefore any library using pure csv-style as input won't work. I've updated the input data,  sorry for the confusion.

Is that { in the input really there, or is it a typo?

It's really there. The original data is loosely something like a json. But sadly it's not well-formed, so the idea to just store it in a database and update it there didn't work out.

You should copy/paste your bash script into http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag and fix the issues it'll tell you about.

This is really hacky, but then so are the input and output formats... Use with One True Awk or GNU awk 5.3+:
awk --csv -v OFS='","' \
  'NR>1 {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {a[i]=$i=$i?$i:a[i]; gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i)} print "\"" $0}'

"Alpha","OldTheme","Some more text"]
"Alpha","OldTheme","Another rest text"]
"Alpha","OldTheme","Yet another text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","Crazy Text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","More crazy text"]


Wow, your solution is very fast. But as explained in this comment, only the first two fields must be changed, the rest is to be left alone. Is there any way to reduce your awk script to only consider the first two fields? The overall process for the huge file took 10seconds vs. 2 hours for my solution or 30min for the this solution

@StefanM Sure, just change i<NF to i<=2. Also note that the gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i) part takes care of doubling any quotes appearing inside of values (according to a CSV encoding). If this doesn't occur in your data, you can speed up even more by replacing {a[i]=$i=$i?$i:a[i]; gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i)} with just a[i]=$i=$i?$i:a[i];.

That works very fine (with gawk 5.3.0) and I've accepted your answer. Could you elaborate on how the part a[i]=$i=$i?$i:a[i];  works?

a is the array storing previous values, i a field number from the iteration (by condition i<=2 only up to 2), and $i the value of that field in the current record. So, read $i ? $i : a[i] as "if the value of field i is not empty (actually: evaluates to true), return that value, otherwise return the array value at position i". As this evaluates to the desired value for a given field, we assign it to that field with $i = …, and since an assignment itself evaluates to the assigned value, we can use that expression to also assign it with a[i] = … to the array item for future records.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E '1d;N;s/^|\n/&\n/g
        :a;s/\n("[^"]*",?)(.*\n.*)\n"",?/\1\n\2\1\n/;ta
        /""/s/\n("[^"]*",?)(.*\n.*)\n("[^"]*",?)/\1\n\2\3\n/;ta
        s/\n(.*)\n/\1/;P;D' file

Delete the first line.
Append the next line and form a two line window throughout the file.
Introduce some newline scaffolding to keep track of which field has been matched.
Form a loop matching the fields of the first line with that of the second, replacing empty fields in the second with their corresponding field in the first line and also bump to the next field.
If a substitution has been made repeat the loop.
If unmatched fields still exist in the second line, bump the next field and repeat.
Once all fields have been replaced/or not, remove the scaffolding, print and delete the first line and go again.

To only change the first two empty fields use:
sed -E '1d;N;s/^((("[^"]*",){2}).*\n)"","",/\1\2/;P;D' file


Thank you for this clever way, especially trying to fill all fields. Sadly only the first two fields should be considered, like I showed in my example file. The "Some more text"-Part contain several more entries and I was trying to make a small example to narrow down the problem. Is there a way to keep the logic but only applying it to the first two fields and just copy the rest of the line as it was, even if a substitution took place?

Sure, just remove the 3rd line. I only put in for completeness. This will copy up to the first two empty fields as long as the 3rd field is not empty.

See edit for exactly only copying the first two fields that are empty.


I have build a solution in bash with the help of sed, but the process
is very, very slow and takes hours to complete. I guess the reason for
the delay is the fact that I'm reading line by line, process these in
bash and write them to a new file. My guess is that a sed script with
variables and on the file itself (-f) could speed up the process
dramatically.

Many of the ways of reading data into the shell are expensive, especially when reading from the standard input.  The shell must avoid reading more data than it is intended to do, which often means reading a single byte at a time.  Your script is likely suffering badly from that.
The script goes on to also fire up bunches of additional processes to get its work done, several per line -- many greps and seds and echos.  It is expensive to start processes.  Having already taken the hit to read the data in, it would be better to do the line processing entirely in the shell.  It's capable of that.
But better still would be do the whole job in one run of a text processing program such as sed or awk.  The latter is much more readable, but you specifically said sed, and you already have an answer for awk. One way to do it with sed would be:
sed -n -E '1n; s/^"","",//; t1; b2; :1; H; g; s/\n//; :2; p; s/^(([^"]*"){4},).*/\1/; h' \
  < input \
  > output

You can script that, of course.
Explanation:
The sed expression is a sequence of commands separated by semicolons (;).  I added a space after each semicolon to make it easier to read; these space are not significant to sed. The commands are:

1n - for line number 1, simply read in the next line.  With the -n command-line option in effect, this completely skips the first line.

s/^"","",// - delete the text "","", from the beginning of the line (substitute an empty string for it), if it is present

t1 - if a substitution was in fact performed then jump ahead to label 1, skipping the commands between here and there. This is what happens for lines with "missing" entries.

b2 - unconditionally jump ahead to label 2, skipping the commands between here and there. This is what happens for new "initial" lines.

:1 - label 1

H - append a newline and the contents of the pattern space to the Hold space (see also below).  The first, empty fields of the pattern space were just deleted, so this copies just the tail.

g - get the contents of the hold space, replacing the contents of the pattern space with them

s/\n// - delete a newline from the pattern space.  This was introduced by the preceding H command.

:2 - label 2. When control reaches this point, the contents of the pattern space look like an initial line, whether they started that way or not.

p - print the contents of the pattern space.

s/^(([^"]*"){4},).*/\1/ - truncate the line after the second quoted string and its trailing comma.  What's left is the part that we want to preserve for use in subsequent non-initial lines.
Each ([^"]*") matches and groups zero or more non-" characters followed by exactly one ".  The {4} requires that that group be matched exactly four times.  The , matches a literal comma.  Enclosing all that in () groups and captures it (this is group 1), and the following .* matches everything else through the end of the line.  The substitution, \1, is a backreference representing the contents of group 1.  Since the pattern matches the whole line, group 1 is all that's left after the substitution.

h - copy the contents of the pattern space to the hold space


With the -n command-line option in effect, there is no automatic printing of the pattern space at the end of the cycle.
Note that if you wanted to preserve the first line instead of dropping it, then you could modify the above very easily to do so.  Simply add a d command at the end, and run without the -n option.

Thank you very much, this is a great explanation on how you used sed and a great example for labels. Although it matches my request, I wasn't specific about the first two fields. My example script analyses each of the two fields seperately whereas your sed example checks for both at a time. I'm sorry that my explanation and my example data wasn't specific in this point. I was hoping that the example script made clear what I had in mind.

Please don't assume we can figure out what you want to do by reading code and don't assume we'll find information spread across comments. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and if you want the 3rd field treated differently from the first 2 then use sample input/output that shows that behavior, e.g. a line where the 3rd field is empty in the input and remains empty in the output.

Using GNU awk for FPAT and multi-char RS and assuming you don't have any ]\n strings inside any fields:
$ cat ./tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    NR == 1 {
        RS = ORS = "]" RS
        OFS = ","
        FPAT = "([^" OFS "]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"
        next
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            $i = ( $i ~ /^("")?$/ ? prev[i] : $i )
            prev[i] = $i
        }
        print
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
"Alpha","OldTheme","Some more text"]
"Alpha","OldTheme","Another rest text"]
"Alpha","OldTheme","Yet another text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","Crazy Text"]
"Yadda","NewTheme","More crazy text"]

If you only want the first 2 fields manipulated then just change i<=NF to i<=2 or i<NF, whichever you prefer.
See What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk? for more information on parsing CSVs with awk.
